# ¿Cuál es la mejor forma de utilizar unbind() para terminar eventos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo este código para realizar una petición por ajax al momento de dar click al botón con la clase "post"

```
// boton presionado con clase post //
$(".post").click(function() {
//Determina cual boton fue presionado
usedBtn = $(this).attr("name");

$(".ajaxFormUpdate").submit(function(e) {
// Animacion mientras se realiza la peticion
    $('#main1').html('<div align="center"><img src="assets/images/loader.gif"/></div>');
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");

    // Add button selector to serialized array postData //
    postData.push({name: 'usedBtn', value: usedBtn });

    $.ajax({
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
  cache: true,
        success:function(data) {
            //$('.post').unbind('click');
            $("#mainContent1").html(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("Connection error");
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    e.unbind();
});
});
```

pero siempre me salta este error en consola.

[image: error en consola]
He intentado con terminar el evento click con

```
   $('.post').unbind('click');
```

en el success, pero siempre me ejecuta la primera petición y no la última.

Si quito la línea:

```
   e.unbind();
```

Con cada petición de ajax que realice con esa función cada vez hace mas request a tal punto de tardar mucho tiempo, pero mientras deje la línea funciona bien.

No se si este utilizando de forma incorrecta unbind, intente también con off() pero sale la misma.

Comment: El método unbind() ya es obsoleto y fue remplazado por off() desde la versión 1.7 de jQuery

Comment: Asi es, es solo que con off() obtengo el mismo resultado..

Comment: Así como el código, los mensajes de error se deben de incluir como texto en lugar de cómo imagen por un lado porque son más fáciles de leer e indexar/encontrar.